# Error "Invalid Instruction" in PL/SQL function using Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, syntax, stored-functions

here i'm trying to create a sort of a boolean function but when i try to compile it, it says me that my instruction "truth INTEGER;" is not correct. I can't figure out where does the problem come from because every code sample that i've seen on Google is quite similar to mine. Using Oracle is totally new for me so i'm kinda lost if someone is okay to help me...

I tried a lot of things by searching but nothing works so i'm here to ask for some help...

CODE:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION HISTOTOX.matching_idipl (iDiplNumero INTEGER) RETURN INTEGER
 AS
  cpt INTEGER;
  truth INTEGER;
 
 BEGIN
         SELECT count(*) INTO cpt FROM GARNUCHE.INSC_DIPL WHERE IDIPL_NUMERO = iDiplNumero;
     IF cpt = 1 THEN 
        truth := 1;
     ELSE
        truth := 0;
     END IF;
        RETURN truth;
 END;
```

Comment: Which client are you running this in, and how? It kind of looks like whatever it is doesn't understand PL/SQL blocks properly, something I think DBeaver used to suffer from. If it took everything up to the first semicolon as one statement, and either ignored it or ran it with an error you didn't show, then saw `truth INTEGER;` as a standalone command... I could imagine it might complain (like "Unknown Command" in SQL Developer if you run just that; or SP-0734 SQL\*Plus), but don't know if any client gives "Invalid Instruction".

Comment: @Zerkioms Please do not edit commentary into an Answer, nor into a Question. Post a *comment* for that. If you have additional information that is needed to properly understand your Question, please [edit] is into your Question, so that it is answerable. See [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056). You may also want to visit the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you reported isn't Oracle error. I *replicated* your code in my 11g and everything works just fine:

```
SQL>  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION matching_idipl (iDiplNumero INTEGER) RETURN INTEGER
  2   AS
  3    cpt INTEGER;
  4    truth INTEGER;
  5
  6   BEGIN
  7           SELECT count(*) INTO cpt FROM INSC_DIPL WHERE IDIPL_NUMERO = iDiplNumero;
  8       IF cpt = 1 THEN
  9          truth := 1;
 10       ELSE
 11          truth := 0;
 12       END IF;
 13          RETURN truth;
 14   END;
 15   /

Function created.

SQL> select matching_idipl(1) from dual;

MATCHING_IDIPL(1)
-----------------
                1

SQL>
```

So: where exactly did you execute that code? Which error did you get (exact message and **error code**, please)?

Comment: this is my execute line : SELECT HISTOTOX.matching_idipl(10) FROM dual;

and my error : 

Package or function GET_ETUD_NUM is in an invalid state

When i got this error i thought the problem came from my code so i compiled it and saw the errors and that's what i got: 

Error Msg = Line 7, column 26:
PL / SQL: ORA-00904: "IDIPLNUMERO": invalid identifier
ORA-06550: Line 2, column 2:
PL / SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: Line 8, column 2:
PLS-00372: The RETURN statement cannot contain an expression in a procedure.
ORA-06550: Line 8, column 2:
PL / SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: ORA-00904 means that there's no column IDIPLNUMERO in that table. Note that code you posted suggests its name is IDIPL_NUMERO. For more info, you should post table description. Another error (about RETURN) says that you tried to RETURN in a **procedure**; that should've been a function, right?

Comment: I can't understand... I mean it's obvious if IDIPLNUMERO is not in the table because it's a parameter of my function. Here i compare IDIPL_NUMERO (that is present in a table) and IDIPLNUMERO (parameter of my function). So why would Oracle search in a table my parameter ? For the return i'm not sure but i'm clearly in a function right here, so why is it talking me about a procedure ?

Comment: As I said: post table description and your latest function code.

Comment: Please update the question with the above, do not place then in another comment.